# derived column is not getting added to DB

Tags: sql-server, ssis

i have a ssis task with Flat file --> derived column-->oledb destination

derived column works as expected but the same is not getting added to my sql-server database !

i have made all settings in derived column `to add as new column`

but i dont get why it does not add up ?

`enabling data viewer shows the column` !

Comment: Can you include some screenshots of the relevant components including where the mappings for the oledb destination columns please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`derived column works as expected but the same is not getting added to my sql-server database !`

you should try mapping the columns in your oledb destination !

map derived column to relevant output column